# Error while calling Python function

Tags: python

I defined a function which takes 2 arguments. When I call the function, I get an error saying not enough argument:

```
>>> def fib(self, a,b):
...   self.i=a, self.j=b
...   print self.i+self.j
... 
>>> fib(4,8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fib() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

>>> fib(4,8,9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in fib
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'i'
```

I passed with both 2 and 3 arguments. What should be the third argument?

Comment: It takes **3** arguments.

Comment: it looks like you defined a class method but I see no class object you are calling `fib` on?

Comment: @EdChum s/class method/method/ - in Python a `classmethod` is a method that takes the class (not the instance) as first argument.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ah thanks for the clarification, coming from c++ background this is a little different to what I'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you don't understand `self` very well in python. Its heading towards OOP (Object oriented programming).

non-OOP approach (doing the same thing with static methods)

```
def fib(a,b):
    print a+b

fib(4,8)
```

OOP approach

```
class Test():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    def fib(self, a,b):
        self.i=a
        self.j=b
        print self.i+self.j

t = Test() # create an object of Test class
t.fib(2, 3) # make the function call
```

**NOTE :** python considers a function to be a static function if it does not have the keyword `self` as the first parameter

Comment: First point: the two variables at the class level are useless and misleading. Second point: there' s no such thing as a "static function" in Pyton. Third point: `self` is not a keyword. Fourth point: not naming a method's first arg `self` makes no difference, the method will get the instance as first argument, as explained here : https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod.

Answer (score 1):

You function has 3 arguments: self, a and b.

self is traditionally used for methods.

You write (simplified example):

```
class A:
   def multiply(self, b): # method called with one argument
       return 2 * b

a = A()
a.multiply(3)
```

or

```
def multiply(b): # this is a function with one argument
    return 2*b

mutiply(3)
```

Comment: s/class method/method/. A `classmethod` is something different (it's a method that takes the class - not the instance - as first argument).

Comment: You're right, bad wording. I have edited the answer.